# Stateful implicit parameters. Is it safe?

Tags: scala, implicit

Since, all implicits are inferred by the compiler is it safe to have stateful implicit parameters? For instance:

```
class TestImplct {
  def test(implicit mc : MyClass) = println(mc.i)
}

class MyClass(val i : Int)
```

and then use it as this

```
implicit val mc = new MyClass(1234)
val ti = new TestImplct
ti.test
```

it works fine, but is it safe or maybe there are some drawbacks about stateful implicits?

Comment: In your example, you don't have any mutable state so I guess you're safe. Things would probably be different if the state was mutable.
Having said that, the "implicit" is just a way to make the compiler provide the parameter for you instead of specifying it explicitly. Any state related drawbacks would probably be more related to mutability than to the implicit itself. The only problem I see is that the implicit makes the dependency on some state more obscure (by reading only the usage-code you're not aware that it depends on MyClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> stateful implicit parameters

I'm not sure what you mean by "stateful": mutable or immutable state?
Immutable state is a-okay; constants aren't dangerous.

Mutable state would be much more dangerous however. I'm not sure what your use case is, but you could in general forget about multi-threading (because you never know if some other function running got it as an implicit and is using it in another thread...).
You're also making it impossible to reason about your code, since implicit resolution is complicated and, by definition, can't be read in the code (because it isn't, well, explicit).